# How to print input when it's a float in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to include the user's response to 'age' in the answer.

However, including 'age' returns an error. Seems to be because it is preceded by float. Is there a way to include the response to 'How old are you?'?

Here's the code:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
age = float(input("How old are you? "))
answer1 = (age + "!? That's very old, " + name + "!")
answer2 = (age + "? You're still young, " + name + ".")
if age > 60:
    print(answer1)
if age < 60:
    print(answer2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike e.g. Java, Python does not automagically call the `__str__` method when concatenating objects some of which are already strings. The way you do it, you would have to convert it to a string manually:

```
answer1 = (str(age) + "!? That's very old, " + name + "!")
```

Consider, however, using proper string formatting in the first place:

```
answer1 = ("{age}!? That's very old, {name}!".format(age=age, name=name))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is there a way to remove the .0 that this adds to the print response? I'm seeing: "65.0!? That's very old..."

Comment: Yes, you can use e.g. `{age:.0f}`. Read the string [formatting docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.

1. Convert age to string:

   `answer1 = (str(age) + ...)`
2. Use old-style string formatting:

   `answer1= "%f!? That's very old, %s!" % (age, name)`
3. Use Python 3.6's excellent string interpolation:

   `answer1 = f"{age}!? That's very old, {name}!"`

I would go with the third.

Comment: There's also a forth way, using `format`, but I never liked it, especially now that string interpolation is available.

Comment: Why don't you like it? `format` is the recommended way before Python3.6. Unlike interpolation, it is available in all Python versions and its usage seems more natural to me than the old-style formatting.

Comment: I guess it's my roots in C. Never liked it, never cared enough to convince others not to like it.